# Can you produce friendly URLs with an ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, friendly-url

I have used ActionLinks to create a page link - for example:

```
@Html.ActionLink(p.Name, "Details", new { URL = p.URL })
```

This generates a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/app/Home/Details?URL=the-cafe-name
```

I would like a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/app/the-cafe-name
```

URL is a value stored with each place.

Is it best practice to use ActionLink here? If so how can I get it to produce friendly URL's (apart form ones containing ID, which is seems to do automatically?).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a route configured with `url` as a parameter name?

Comment: Yes. I can type 
 

I have used ActionLinks to create a page link - for example:

@Html.ActionLink(p.Name, "Details", new { URL = p.URL })

This generates a URL like this:

http://localhost/app/Home/Details?URL=the-cafe-name

I would like a URL like this:

http://localhost/app/the-cafe-name - in the browser - works fine. I was just wondering if I should use an ActionLink to render this URL?

Comment: In your route config file, what does the route definition look like? Are you sure you've created a new route that expects a `url` parameter? Can you paste the code you've got in your route config file?

Comment: From the future - I now use Attribute Routing - which I'd recommend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a MapRoute like this as your last route

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UrlFriendly",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "UrlFriendly", action = "Index" }
        );
```

If you have a complex website you'll need to handle all cases, and this could be a big amount of work!

Comment: Could you explain how this would handle the OP's desired url of `http://localhost/app/the-cafe-name`?

Comment: You can use the whildchar * to handle it, like  
url: "app/{*url}",
In this way all the url who start with "app/" will be handled with your UrlFriendly controller

Comment: From the future - I now use Attribute Routing - which I'd recommend.